# how to assign colour to duplicate values in a list

Tags: c#, .net, linq

how to assign colour to duplicate values in a list

This my table

```
| user_id | account_no | zip   |      date |
|       1 |        123 | 55555 | 12-DEC-09 | 
|       1 |        123 | 66666 | 12-DEC-09 |
|       1 |        123 | 55555 | 13-DEC-09 |
|       2 |        456 | 77777 | 14-DEC-09 |
|       2 |        456 | 77777 | 14-DEC-09 |
|       2 |        789 | 77777 | 14-DEC-09 |
|       2 |        789 | 77777 | 14-DEC-09 |
```

Comment: What exactly do you need?

Answer (score 0):

You can assign a color in this way:

```
var userIdGroups = db.TableName.GroupBy(x => x.user_id).AsEnumerable();
var itemsWithColors = userIdGroups
    .SelectMany(g => g.Select((x, index) => index == 0
        ? new { Item = x, Color = Color.Black }
        : new { Item = x, Color = Color.Red   }));
```

Now use a `foreach` loop to process this query and add these items to your UI control.